# What effect has MaxAuthTries=1?

Tags: ssh

I configure a new server right now and ask myself what is the internally effect if I set MaxAuthTries=1 in sshd_config.
The server only accept key authentication an no root logins.

Has this setting any effect to prevent brute force logins?

Is there any effect more than closing the tcp socket after MaxAuthTries wrong authentications? Maybe some internal blacklisting for a period or stuff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> MaxAuthTries
>
> Specifies the maximum number of authentication attempts permitted per connection. Once the number of failures reaches half this value, additional failures are logged. The default is 6.

[Man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config)

Setting the value to 1 will mean that your server will only allow 1 login attempt before locking you out.

Comment: If I got the man page right is the only effect that sshd close the tcp socket after MaxAuthTries wrong connection tries. I thing this is no great security benefit :-D

Comment: @OkieOth It slows brute force attacks

Comment: It also annoys your users if they have keys and/or other authentication methods ;-) Each method counts as an "attempt" of course. (One workaround is a suitable `Host` stanza in `~/.ssh/config`.) As `sshd` just drops the connection, it only makes it marginally more time consuming for an attacker, leaving other more effective defence layers such as TCP connection rate limiting to kick in.

Comment: @Terry today I found the special behavior related to the syslog you mentioned. That's really nice ... if MaxAuthTries=1 and log level is INFO every login failure is logged in /var/log/auth ... good for fail2ban :-D